# Make sidebar not collapsable and always expanded in docusaurus V2 classic preset

Tags: docusaurus

If you use classic template when creating the doc, you'll get a sidebar like this:

[image]
(Docusaurus v2)

How can I **keep using this preset and have a sidebar always expanded like this**:

[image]
(ComponentKit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sidebar collapsing is a theme configuration attribute. You can modify this:

```js
// docusaurus.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  themeConfig: {
    sidebarCollapsible: false,
    // ...
  },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The `sidebarCollapsible` option has now moved to the `docs` section of the `presets` config:

```
const config = {
  presets: [
    [
      "classic",
      /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').Options} */
      ({
        docs: {
          sidebarPath: require.resolve("./sidebars.js"),
          sidebarCollapsible: false,
        },
       ...
       )
     ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: If you just want to start expanded, there is also the option `sidebarCollapsed`